# RDS | Is there a way to identify what queries consume the most IOPS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

We are currently hitting the limits of allocated IOPS on our DB and this got me wondering how can we identify what is contributing the most to our IOPS usage.

We can see what queries are run, how long they took, how many times those queries were run but this doesn't directly answer the question of what queries are using up all the IOPS of the postgresql RDS db and we have to make educated guesses. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is simple if you can install `pg_stat_statements` and set `track_io_timing = on`.

The `pg_stat_statements` extension provides a view of the same name that you can query like this:

```
SELECT query,
       blk_read_time + blk_write_time AS io_time
FROM pg_stat_statements
ORDER BY blk_read_time + blk_write_time DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

There are two drawback with this:

- Since PostgreSQL uses buffered I/O, a read or write does not necessarily go to disk, but can go to the operating system kernel cache, not actually causing I/O. But since such I/O requests are fast, they should only cause a small fraction of the result.
- The bigger problem is that because of the architecture of a relational database, you won't see most write requests there, because writes normally happen during checkpoints and cannot be attributed to an individual query.

Because of that, it might be better to track `shared_blks_dirtied + shared_blks_written` than `blk_write_time`, which won't tell you the I/O time, but give you a good idea how many 8kB blocks this query caused to be written.

Even if you don't get exact numbers that way, `pg_stat_statements` will give you a good idea which statements cause the most I/O.

Comment: This is great and definitely sheds some light. To follow up, would you know if there's a way to correlate IO consumed with a timespan rather than the all time IO consumed? For example, if I notice I'm hitting my max IOPS this hour, I wonder if there there could be a query not at the top of the list but is growing very fast in IOPS usage, is there a way to identify that?

Comment: You are right that `blk_write_time` appears to always be 0. Since `shared_blks_dirtied + shared_blks_written` can replace `blk_write_time`, would `shared_blks_read` be a replacement for  `blk_read_time`? If we wanted to compare how our write IOPS compared to our read IOPS using blks?

Comment: `shared_blocks_read` can be a very bad approximation to generated I/O, if the kernel cache is large and caches a lot of database data. On the other hand, a dirtied or written page will usually cause an I/O request. To get data over time, take regular snapshots of `pg_stat_activity` and calculate the difference.

Comment: What does the kernel in kernel cache refer to? Does that cache exist on the database server or is that lower level like on the OS?

Comment: That's the operating system kernel. On most Unix systems, you can run `free` and see "buf/cache" as the amount of memory not in use for any process and used to cache files.